# Cypher query for aggregated data of repeating patterns of relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'd be happy to receive your advice about a query, with the image below.

There are four parties (with ID no. 0-3, in orange) and I would like to present aggregated data about how the participants :PARTICIPATED in the parties.

The query should provide data about: How many unique participants participated in 1,2,3 or 4 parties? And, to which parties did they go? (or: what are the different party combinations?)

Example of output (not based on the image below, just to illustrate the output)

**Parties ID Combination** **0,2,3**  | 3 parties in total | 5 participants

**Parties ID Combination** **0,1,2**  | 3 parties in total | 4 participants

**Parties ID Combination 1,3**  | 2 parties in total | 3 participants

I realize that a solution could be testing each participants for a collection of arrays (=party combinations), but i'm not sure how to implement it, and it doesn't sound very promising performance-wise.

I'd appreciate your help - thanks in advance!

[image: parties]

Comment: Please explain the criteria you use to get your expected output.

Comment: Hi Cybersam - If I understood your question correctly, the criteria is to show all the combinations of parties' ID, having more than 1 participants that participated this combination.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. For your "Combination 0,2,3", can you indicate how you got 5 participants?

Comment: Got it now - this was just an example of the output, it's not based on the data. (I'll update it in the post)

Comment: The wording is not clear enough for me to understand what you are trying to do. Can you show how to get an actual answer, maybe using a simpler graph?

Comment: Hi, Thanks again. I'm not sure I can explain it better with a simpler graph. If you don't mind I'll try to write down a use case - Let's say you are sending one email promotion about 4 different parties, one party for each month (January to April).Now we are after April, and you want to see how people responded to your email promotion. Some people went to 4 parties, some to 3 parties (out of 4), and so on. Now, I want to see to WHICH parties they went - Let's look at those who went to 3 parties: How many went to the parties on January, February and March? How many to February, March and April?

Answer (score 0):

That's a tough one.  Not sure how to do it in one query, but I think you could do it with four queries.  This would be an example of matching on three parties:

```
MATCH (party1:Party), (party2:Party), (party3:Party)
WHERE ID(party1) < ID(party2) AND ID(party2) < ID(party3)
WITH [ID(party1), ID(party2), ID(party3)] AS party_ids
MATCH (party:Party)<-[:PARTICIPATED]-(participant)
WHERE ID(party) IN (party_ids)
RETURN party_ids, count(DISTINCT participant)
```

Comment: Thanks for the follow up Brian. It indeed matches all the parties combinations possible on the left column, but on the right column, where I have the "count", it displays the total number of participants in the graph, for each parties combination. Something in the query has to restrict the count of participants for the parties combination in each row. Any idea how? Perhaps doing it in Cypher alone isn't the right approach, and I should iterate it with different parties combinations?

Comment: Just made a change which may help.  How does it work?

Comment: Thanks Brian! I think we are getting somewhere - the problem now is that the 5th line behaves like an OR boolean - the "count" shows results of participants that participated in ONE OR MORE of the party_ids, rather of participants who participated in ALL of the party_ids in question. Any idea how to restrict it further?